# php 'ISSET' function not working. OR the code skips my if statements

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

The not working and i get the same error output as defined in the last else statement.

I am new to Php, please help me out. What am I doing wrong?

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
<form action="imagespace.php?groupid=<?php echo $_GET['groupid'] ;?>" method = "POST">
<input type="button" name="Up-Vote" value ="Up-Vote" class="up-votes" />
<input type="button" name="Down-Vote" value="Down-Vote" class="down-votes" />
</form>
<?php

$emailid=$_SESSION['emailid'];
$groupid = $_GET['groupid'];
$emailid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$emailid);
$groupid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$emailid);

if(isset($_POST['Up-Vote']))
    { echo ' trial';
    $query = "INSERT into VOTES (emailid, groupid, vote) values ('$emailid','$groupid', '1') ";
    $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
    if($query_run)
    {echo 'upvoted';}
    }

else if(isset($_POST['Down-Vote']))
    {
        $query = "INSERT into VOTES (emailid, groupid, vote) values ('$emailid','$groupid', '0') ";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($con,$query);
        if($query_run)
        {echo 'downvoted';}
    }
else{
echo 'error' ;
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code, not pictures of it.

Comment: as @AlexHowansky said, at least post your code then what is "not working" ?

Comment: don't use in post variables upvote/downvote, just use vote with values 1 or -1, it will be easier.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` will tell you exactly what is in your post variable.

Comment: You're not posting anything; the easiest solution is probably to change your buttons from `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

Comment: @kRicha  i am using 0 for downvote and 1 for upvote

Comment: @Learner it's useless functionality.

Comment: @jeroen i dont know how to tag you. but yes your solution worked but i dont know why i always have 'Error' echoed at the corner even without clicking on the buttons.

Comment: Just remove that last `else` section, it simply means the form has not been posted yet and that should not lead to an error but just show the form.

Comment: @kRicha it is useful, Just like everyone is downvoting my question here. ;p

Comment: 2 downvotes is hardly everyone :-)

Comment: Thank you all guys it is working now. This is the first time I posted a question on Stack overflow and the response was overwhelming. Amazing Site for Beginners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the supplied answer(s), I would like to suggest doin the following:

```
// Before anything else, start your session
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

// Next, check if your form is actually submitted
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['...'])) {

    } elseif (isset($_POST['...'])) {

    }
}
?>

<!-- Keep PHP and html seperated -->
<form>
...
</form>
```

By looking at your form, i notice that you are using `type='button'`. I suggest one of the following:

```
<input type="submit" ... />

<button type="submit">...</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to find a submit button in there. Try adding

```
<input type="submit" />
```

right before the closing `</form>`-tag. Then try if the error still occurs if you click on it.

Also, try using checkboxes/radio buttons instead of buttons. I don't know whether it is possible to do that with buttons.

Comment: I ll try this and revert back in a few mins. Thanks for this bro.

Answer (score 0):

The extra submit button isn't needed, the `<button>`s act same in default type.